# PrimeFaces: javax.el.ELException adding a menu choice

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

I'm trying to port an application from RichFaces to PrimeFaces to check the performance differences. When I add the Logout menu choice (that works using RIchFaces)...

```
<h:form>
   <p:toolbar>
      <p:toolbarGroup align="left">  
          <p:menubar>  
             <p:submenu label="My Account" icon="ui-icon-person">  
             <p:menuitem  value="Modify my Data" url="#{participantBean.modifyUser(participantBean.principal)}" icon="ui-icon-pencil" />
             <p:menuitem  value="Change Password" url="#{participantBean.modifyPassword(participantBean.principal)}" />
             <p:menuitem  value="Logout" url="#{auth.logout()}" />
          </p:submenu>
         </p:menubar>
      </p:toolbarGroup>
    </p:toolbar>
</h:form>
```

I receive the following exception

```
javax.el.ELException: /secure/index.xhtml @30,85 url="#{auth.logout()}":     java.lang.IllegalStateException
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:114)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
at org.primefaces.component.menuitem.UIMenuItem.getUrl(UIMenuItem.java:99)
at org.primefaces.component.menuitem.UIMenuItem.getHref(UIMenuItem.java:292)
at    org.primefaces.renderkit.OutcomeTargetRenderer.getTargetURL(OutcomeTargetRenderer.java:73)
at org.primefaces.component.menu.BaseMenuRenderer.encodeMenuItem(BaseMenuRenderer.java:148)
at org.primefaces.component.tieredmenu.TieredMenuRenderer.encodeElements(TieredMenuRenderer.java:103)
at org.primefaces.component.tieredmenu.TieredMenuRenderer.encodeSubmenu(TieredMenuRenderer.java:162)
at org.primefaces.component.tieredmenu.TieredMenuRenderer.encodeElements(TieredMenuRenderer.java:119)
at org.primefaces.component.tieredmenu.TieredMenuRenderer.encodeMenu(TieredMenuRenderer.java:78)
at org.primefaces.component.menubar.MenubarRenderer.encodeMarkup(MenubarRenderer.java:49)
at org.primefaces.component.menu.BaseMenuRenderer.encodeEnd(BaseMenuRenderer.java:105)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1764)
at org.primefaces.component.toolbar.ToolbarRenderer.encodeEnd(ToolbarRenderer.java:61)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1764)
at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1757)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendRedirect(ResponseFacade.java:524)
at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.redirect(ExternalContextImpl.java:576)
at Beans.Auth.logout(Auth.java:73)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invokeMethod(BeanELResolver.java:779)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:528)
at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:257)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:134)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:224)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
... 52 more
```

The logout method is in the Auth bean:

```
public class Auth implements Serializable {

/**
 * Creates a new instance of Auth
 */
public Auth() {
}
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Inject
private ParticipantDAO userService;
private String email;
private String password;
private String originalURL;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    originalURL = (String) externalContext.getRequestMap().get(RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_REQUEST_URI);

    if (originalURL == null) {
        originalURL = externalContext.getRequestContextPath() + "/secure/index.xhtml";
    } else {
        String originalQuery = (String) externalContext.getRequestMap().get(RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_QUERY_STRING);

        if (originalQuery != null) {
            originalURL += "?" + originalQuery;
        }
    }
}

public void login() throws IOException, ServletException {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext externalContext = context.getExternalContext();
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) externalContext.getRequest();

    try {
        request.login(email, password);
        Participant user = userService.findUser(email, password);
        externalContext.getSessionMap().put("user", user);
        externalContext.redirect(originalURL);
    } catch (ServletException e) {
        // Handle unknown username/password in request.login().
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Unknown login or wrong password"));
    }
}

public void logout() throws IOException {
    ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    externalContext.invalidateSession();
    externalContext.redirect(externalContext.getRequestContextPath() + "/secure/login.xhtml");
}
```

Where I wrong?

---

If I apply your modification I obtain:

```
com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean participantBean
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:229)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:105)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:103)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:179)
at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:224)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextVariable.writeText(ELText.java:227)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextComposite.writeText(ELText.java:150)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:85)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:82)
at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:67)
at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:57)
at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:204)
at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(PanelRenderer.java:121)
at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:58)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1764)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    Caused by: com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderException: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting invoke lifecycle  method public void Beans.ParticipantBean.init()
at org.glassfish.faces.integration.GlassFishInjectionProvider.invokePostConstruct(GlassFishInjectionProvider.java:231)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:223)
... 55 more
  Caused by: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting invoke lifecycle  method public void Beans.ParticipantBean.init()
at org.glassfish.faces.integration.GlassFishInjectionProvider.invokeLifecycleMethod(GlassFishInjectionProvider.java:393)
at org.glassfish.faces.integration.GlassFishInjectionProvider.invokePostConstruct(GlassFishInjectionProvider.java:306)
at org.glassfish.faces.integration.GlassFishInjectionProvider.invokePostConstruct(GlassFishInjectionProvider.java:229)
... 56 more
    Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.glassfish.faces.integration.GlassFishInjectionProvider.invokeLifecycleMethod(GlassFishInjectionProvider.java:376)
... 58 more
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.glassfish.faces.integration.GlassFishInjectionProvider$2.run(GlassFishInjectionProvider.java:382)
... 60 more
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at Beans.ParticipantBean.init(ParticipantBean.java:408)
... 65 more
```

---

After Yamada UPDATE I obtain:

```
WARNING: #{auth.login()}: java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.faces.FacesException: #{auth.login()}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
... 31 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at Beans.Auth.login(Auth.java:67)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invokeMethod(BeanELResolver.java:779)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:528)
at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:257)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:248)
at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
... 32 more
```

The line 67 in Auth is findUser query

```
  public void login() throws IOException, ServletException {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext externalContext = context.getExternalContext();
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) externalContext.getRequest();

    try {
        request.login(email, password);
        Participant user = userService.findUser(email, password);
        externalContext.getSessionMap().put("user", user);
        externalContext.redirect(originalURL);
    } catch (ServletException e) {
        // Handle unknown username/password in request.login().
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Unknown login or wrong password"));
    }
}
```

That works fine using RichFaces.

The findUser method is in participanDAO class:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
@DeclareRoles({"SUPERADMINISTRATOR", "ADMINISTRATOR", "USER"})
public class ParticipantDAO {

/**
 * Creates a new instance of ParticipantDAO
 */
public ParticipantDAO() {
}
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
@Resource
SessionContext context;

public Participant findUser(String email, String password) {
    password = DigestUtils.sha512Hex(password);
    TypedQuery<Participant> query = em.createNamedQuery(Participant.FIND_USER, Participant.class).setParameter("email", email).setParameter("password", password);
    List<Participant> results = query.getResultList();
    Participant user = null;
    if (!results.isEmpty()) {
        // ignores multiple results
        user = results.get(0);
    }
    return user;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The url attribute expects an url string. Your EL method is returning void.

Try changing your logout method to this:

```
public String logout() throws IOException {
ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
externalContext.invalidateSession();
return externalContext.getRequestContextPath() + "/secure/login.xhtml";
```

}

**UPDATE**

Declare your Auth MB like this:

```
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
@Named(value = "auth")
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Auth implements Serializable {
...
```

Also declare the ParticipantBean SessionScoped to check if it is related to the scope of your MBs.

Comment: If apply your suggestion I obtain another exception, like I reported in the main post.

Comment: How do you declare the scope of your Auth MB?

Comment: You are obviosly getting NPE on `Beans.ParticipantBean.init(ParticipantBean.java:408)`. Try fixing that first.

Comment: @Yamada Auth hasn't scope.

Comment: @awb the code works fine using Richfaces. I don't know why using Primefaces I have these problem.

Comment: ` @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        principal = externalContext.getSessionMap().get("user").toString();
        principalData = participantDAO.getByEmail(principal);

    }`

Comment: Have you solved the NullPointerException
at Beans.ParticipantBean.init(ParticipantBean.java:408) as pointed by awb? Probably you are using the PF components in a wrong way, I can tell you that PF works great.

Comment: @Yamada I posted the init just before your comment. I don't see nothing to be wrong. Is it possible that Auth.login() didn't put user in the SessionMap?

Comment: I'm going crazy :-(( I tried to start by zero, but I continue to receive NPE now from Auth class. I don't understand why things that works with RichFaces doesn't works with PrimeFaces.

Comment: @Yamada applying you suggestion I obtain another exception, like you see in the last lines of my question

Comment: I don't know very well java-ee but I don't understand why changing Netbeans version I have different behaviour of the code. The problems described in this post has been using 7.1.1. Now using 7.3.1 I haven't the exception, I'm able to pass the login phase and enter in the secured area, but when I select a menu item I return to the login page.

Comment: Have you solved the issue yet? Looking at your jsf code, `<p:menuItem>` doesnt seem to be correct. You should probably use attribute `action="#{auth.logout()}"` instead of `url`. And, well, if you somehow use this for logging in, who knows what is going to happen? Anyway, you should check if `password` and `email` fields are set and are not null before logging in.